# How change child components value which is passed from parent without state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't solve this case.
It's from parent

```
  <ChildDiv  key={el} width={i} value={' '}></ChildDiv>
```

It's from Child

```
  <MyContext.Consumer>
      {context => (
        <div onClick={() => test(value, context.ChangeTurn)} className="row">
   </div>
  )}
 </MyContext.Consumer>

   let test = (value, context) => {
if (value !== "X" && val !== "O") {
  value = "laslda";
 }};
```

So I want change value from local function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want context consumers to be able to update the context, it's better to expose a method within the context to perform the update; the component provider can then pass a new context object to consumers, provoking a re-render.

Here's what the code could look like:

Context (`./context.js`):

```js
import { createContext } from 'react';

const Context = createContext({ value: null, setValue: () => {} });

export default Context;
```

Provider (`./provider.js`):

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Context from './context';

const Provider = ({ value: startingValue, children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(startingValue);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Sample consumer (`./consumer.js`):

```js
import Context from './context';

export default Context.Consumer;
```

Now you can do this at your root (`./app.js`):

```js
import Provider from './provider';
import ChildComponent from './child-component';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider value={0}>
      <ChildComponent/>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

...and this in child components (using hooks, `./child-component.js`):

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Context from './context';

export default function ChildComponent() {
  const { value, setValue } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {value}</h1>
      <button onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); setValue(value - 1) }}>-</button>
      <button onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); setValue(value + 1) }}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...or without hooks:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Consumer from './consumer';

export default function ChildComponent() {
  return (
    <Consumer>
      ({ value, setValue }) => (
        <div>
          <h1>Counter: {value}</h1>
          <button onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); setValue(value - 1) }}>-</button>
          <button onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); setValue(value + 1) }}>+</button>
        </div>
      );
    </Consumer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In react, props like the `value` you passing, are [**Read-Only**](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#props).

> Remember that props are readonly. They should not be modified in any way.

You may want to provide a setter:

```
<MyContext.Provider value={{ dispatch: this.setState }}>
  <ChildDiv key={el} width={i} value={value}></ChildDiv>
</MyContext.Provider>

<MyContext.Consumer>
  {({ dispatch }) => (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({value: 'New Value'})}>Button</button>
  )}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: I think with this solution every row will take the same result. At this case I'm trying to set 'X' or 'Y' ,but if I set something state from context, context will share that value to other components too, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You may want to approach it in another way, we can guess what you trying to achieve here.

Comment: I'n trying to set one unique value to each row. In Parent Component I'm creating Div component, in which I'm also creating ChildDiv's component for several time, and this way I'm creating box. But after click on this box's each row, I wrote logic, according which I set X or O value to row, but I can't append it to div.